# Unable to mount an NTFS drive

Tags: mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

I am trying to manually mount an NTFS drive to `/e`. `/e` has the permissions `drwxrwxr-x   2 root root`

I tried the following commands, but none work.I get no error message, but the drive is not mounted:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /e
sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /e 
sudo mount -t ntfs-3G /dev/sdb2 /e
```

If I click the drive in [Thunar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/thunar), it automatically mounts to `/media/joshua/Storage`.

When I execute `cat /proc/mounts`, I see the drive is mounted as follows:

`/dev/sdb2 /media/joshua/Storage fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0`

So I try doing that manually with the mount command:

```
sudo mount -t fuseblk /dev/sdb2 /e 
sudo mount -t fuseblk -o rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 /dev/sdb2 /e
```

but I get the following error:

`mount: /e: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

And I get the same error if I instead try to manually mount to `/media/joshua/Storage`.

**How do I manually mount this drive to /e**?

Comment: Use lowercase: `mount -o ntfs-3g`. See `man ntfs-3g`.